# react link externo

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, routerlink

como puedo hacer para que este link externo funcione?. Esto es en react-router-dom me abre un link dentro de mi proyecto, cuando yo quiero que vaya a la web de google

```
<Link to="https://www.google.com.ar/" target="_blank">Ir a Google </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

La única solución que conozco es que hagas esto:

```
<button onClick={handleClick} >Ir a Google</button>
```

Y antes del return pongas:

```
const handleClick = ()=>{
window.open('https://www.google.com.ar/', '_blank')
}
```

Es la única forma que conozco

Answer (score 0):

El elemento Link que usas de react-router-dom sirve para manejar las rutas dentro de tu aplicación, en caso de querer usar un link externo como comentas, puedes usar el elemento "anchor" de HTML que fue diseñado para usar hipervínculos.

Por ejemplo:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com.ar/">Ir a Google</a>
```